# Apply tooltip to each cell

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I have a table that has 50 more rows and 3 columns. I want to apply a tooltip to each cell. Which means each cell has a different tooltip text. So the table has 50*3 =150 tooltips.

Can we do it? Could you please modify my test [example?](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/LUUkB/2/)

Thanks.

Comment: nobody programs a tooltip from scratch anymore. just use one of the **many many** jQuery plugins. They are tested in all kinds of browsers and work very well **and will save you a lot of work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, I would recommend using an actual plugin instead of your own just because it will be more fully developed and easier to use (and less bugs!). I've personally used the [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) plugin with great success.

Comment: Can qTip add tootip at cell's level?

Answer (score 0):

What about just changing the text in your DIV on mousemove? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ybbjQ/3/) is my updated fiddle. Here is basically all I added:

```
$("#ToolTipDIv").text('Specific Tip for ' + $(this).text());
```